How is delegated stake balance calculated?
I created my staking account with 1 + 0.00228288 (rent-exempt) SOL. So that my initial delegated stake was exactly 1 SOL.
After 6 epochs, my balance is 1.004707281. And my delegated stake is 1.002078092. However, 1.004707281 - 0.00228288 is equal to 1.002424401.
Now I do not understand the relation between total balance, delegated stake, and rewards.
Could you explain me why delegated stake does not match balance - rent exempt ?
My staking account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/4MLwjVi8R7w36Zxu1f82uL159hxLap2AD78PXPuDqDNb

According to stakewiz, the validator you're delegated to, CcaHc2L43ZWjwCHART3oZoJvHLAe9hzT2DJNUpBzoTN1, runs the Jito MEV client https://stakewiz.com/validator/CcaHc2L43ZWjwCHART3oZoJvHLAe9hzT2DJNUpBzoTN1 and distributes a portion of MEV rewards to its stakers.
These MEV rewards come in the form of unstaked SOL, which is why your account has been credited with extra unstaked SOL.
In general, stake accounts can have any amount of unstaked SOL on them, just like any other account on the network. For example, I can transfer more SOL to your stake account, and it wouldn't increase that difference between your delegated stake and balance - rent_exemption.

when I do the calculation: Balance - MEV rewards - rent exemption, it is indeed equal to the delegated balance. thank you so much!
